# Displaying only last added item on cart page, if not logged in

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product

In WooCommerce, my products are listed in category page with details as well as "Add to Cart" button. When user clicked on the button page refreshed and on the top success message with view cart button appeared.

when a user does it for multiple times(add more than one items):

- If the user is logged in the cart page listed all the items with calculation.
- but **if the user is not logged in, the user only see the last item listed in cart page**.

I need to list the cart added products for not logged in user..Can anyone have the solution for this...

Here is my loop/add-to-cart.php code:

```
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
    sprintf( '<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" data-quantity="%s" class="button %s product_type_%s">%s</a>',
        esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
        esc_attr( $product->id ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
        $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
        esc_attr( $product->product_type ),
        esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
    ),
$product );
```

Comment: I think session value is not working when user not logged in

Comment: this is a default practice for Woocommerce, instead of editing Woocommerce code, configure your options or figure out what is causing Woocoomerce to fail
if you can share a link maybe we can help you better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Updated and checked the code (2)
>
>   Cart count works and cart page displays only last cart item for non logged users**
>
> 1) When you are not logged in, **only** last cart item is displayed.
>   2) When you are logged in, all cart items are displayed.

---

This is possible editing the woocommerce **`cart.php`** template.

> You will need first to copy to your active child theme (or theme) folder, the WooCommerce **`templates`** folder located in your **`woocommerce`** plugin folder (if not done yet) and rename that newly added folder **`woocommerce`**. [See this related documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/).

Once done, you will open edit **`cart/cart.php`** file and replace the code by the following:

```
<?php
/**
 * Cart Page
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/cart/cart.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author  WooThemes
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 2.3.8
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

wc_print_notices();

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart' ); ?>

<form action="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ); ?>" method="post">

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_table' );

        // Cart count
        $the_cart = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();

        // initialising counter for the loop (out of it)
        $count = 0;

        // CHECKING JUST THE CART COUNT - TO BE REMOVED
        echo '<p style="font-style:italic; color: grey; margin:10px;">(Debug Info only - Cart count: <strong>'. WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() . '</strong> item(s))</p>';
?>

<table class="shop_table shop_table_responsive cart" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="product-remove">&nbsp;</th>
            <th class="product-thumbnail">&nbsp;</th>
            <th class="product-name"><?php _e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <th class="product-price"><?php _e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <th class="product-quantity"><?php _e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <th class="product-subtotal"><?php _e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_contents' ); ?>

        <?php
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            $_product   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
            $product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

            if( is_user_logged_in() || ( !is_user_logged_in() &&  $count == $cart_count) ):

            // adding 1 to counter
            $count++;

            if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
                $product_permalink = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_permalink', $_product->is_visible() ? $_product->get_permalink( $cart_item ) : '', $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                ?>
                <tr class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'cart_item', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ); ?>">

                    <td class="product-remove">
                        <?php
                            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', sprintf(
                                '<a href="%s" class="remove" title="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s">&times;</a>',
                                esc_url( WC()->cart->get_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
                                __( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ),
                                esc_attr( $product_id ),
                                esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() )
                            ), $cart_item_key );
                        ?>
                    </td>

                    <td class="product-thumbnail">
                        <?php
                            $thumbnail = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                            if ( ! $product_permalink ) {
                                echo $thumbnail;
                            } else {
                                printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $thumbnail );
                            }
                        ?>
                    </td>

                    <td class="product-name" data-title="<?php _e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                        <?php
                            if ( ! $product_permalink ) {
                                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_title(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) . '&nbsp;';
                            } else {
                                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $_product->get_title() ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                            }

                            // Meta data
                            echo WC()->cart->get_item_data( $cart_item );

                            // Backorder notification
                            if ( $_product->backorders_require_notification() && $_product->is_on_backorder( $cart_item['quantity'] ) ) {
                                echo '<p class="backorder_notification">' . esc_html__( 'Available on backorder', 'woocommerce' ) . '</p>';
                            }
                        ?>
                    </td>

                    <td class="product-price" data-title="<?php _e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                        <?php
                            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price( $_product ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                        ?>
                    </td>

                    <td class="product-quantity" data-title="<?php _e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                        <?php
                            if ( $_product->is_sold_individually() ) {
                                $product_quantity = sprintf( '1 <input type="hidden" name="cart[%s][qty]" value="1" />', $cart_item_key );
                            } else {
                                $product_quantity = woocommerce_quantity_input( array(
                                    'input_name'  => "cart[{$cart_item_key}][qty]",
                                    'input_value' => $cart_item['quantity'],
                                    'max_value'   => $_product->backorders_allowed() ? '' : $_product->get_stock_quantity(),
                                    'min_value'   => '0'
                                ), $_product, false );
                            }

                            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', $product_quantity, $cart_item_key, $cart_item );
                        ?>
                    </td>

                    <td class="product-subtotal" data-title="<?php _e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                        <?php
                            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', WC()->cart->get_product_subtotal( $_product, $cart_item['quantity'] ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                        ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }

            endif;

        }

        do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_contents' );
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6" class="actions">

                <?php if ( wc_coupons_enabled() ) { ?>
                    <div class="coupon">

                        <label for="coupon_code"><?php _e( 'Coupon:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label> <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="input-text" id="coupon_code" value="" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Coupon code', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" /> <input type="submit" class="button" name="apply_coupon" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Apply Coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />

                        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_coupon' ); ?>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>

                <input type="submit" class="button" name="update_cart" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Update Cart', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />

                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_actions' ); ?>

                <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-cart' ); ?>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_contents' ); ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_table' ); ?>

</form>

<div class="cart-collaterals">

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_collaterals' ); ?>

</div>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart' ); ?>
```

Then save.

As you will see on line 31 to 38 (outside the cat foreach loop), I have added some code to get the total cart items count and initialized a counter to zero. Also I have temporarily displayed the cart count *(You can remove this line as it's only for testing)*.

I have add a conditional if statement that is going to do what you are expecting:

```
if( is_user_logged_in() || ( !is_user_logged_in() &&  $count == $cart_count) ):
```

Just after this condition I increment the **`$count`** variable (which is in the condition).

> **This is tested and works perfectly now…**

Comment: This is not working ....The value is always 1 for WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count()

Comment: @Lipsa I have tested this time and make some little changes. **It's working perfectly**. Please, feel free to try it on my live raw test server (You got the accesses at the beginning of my answer). And **`WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count()` is working perfectly** to get the numbers of items in cart

Comment: Thanks a lot @LoicTheAztec